# Assigning elements of one list to elements of another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm programming a simulation of Einstein Solids within Python, if you don't know what that is it's fine its relatively simple when dumbed down to boxes and balls, i need to distribute the balls among the boxes and boxes can contain more than one ball but obviously one box cant be split among several balls. The user inputs the number of balls and boxes so they're not constants. I'm new to coding and the logic dead-ends on this one are killing me if someone has an idea that would be great.

for context, in the analogy in reference to my code, the boxes are oscillators and the balls are energy.

The logic pathway I'm on currently is to create a list with length being the number of boxes, and the individual elements just being the 'order' of the boxes, and doing the same for the balls, creating a list with the number of balls being the length. I was on the idea of just finding the probability of a ball landing in one box and essentially doing coin flips for each of the boxes with that probability instead of 1/2 but that doesn't insure that every ball that was given is put into a box and all need to be accounted for.

```
Na=raw_input( "What is the amount of oscillators within object 1? (a positive integer, Na)")
Nb=raw_input( "What is the amount of oscillators within object 2? (a positive integer, Nb)")
N_tot=int((raw_input( "What is the total amount of oscillators within the system? (a positive integer that=Na+Nb)")))

NaList=[]
Na_calc=int(Na)
While Na_calc>0
    NaList.append(Na_calc)
    Na_calc=Na_calc-1
```

I'm ultimately expected to simulate a bunch of different 'ball drops' where the energy is distributed among the oscillators and do more analysis about how several of these would interact but the before mentioned problem about distributing a list to a list would solve the largest logic problem,

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the above example might not be what you're asking for in your question, but perhaps you could use list comprehension to simplify what you are doing in your example

```py
na_list = [n for n in range(na_calc, 0, -1)]
```

However what i feel like your question is about is more likely to be solved using something like zip.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: thank you for your reply, seriously, zip is neat and would be helpful but I'm not just appending each element of the two lists together in exact order, there is going to need to be an if statement involved as to whether or not the box gets a ball but zip may be useful later on. and thanks for the code shortcuts

Comment: `na_list = [n for n in range(na_calc, 0, -1) if my_random_condition(n)]` might be helpful then.